# Mysql 5.7 slow CASE WHEN THEN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching friend relationship using the following query:

```
SELECT F.friend_one, F.friend_two, F.requested_id, F.status
FROM users U, friends F
WHERE
CASE
WHEN F.friend_one = 2
THEN F.friend_two = U.id
WHEN F.friend_two= 2 
THEN F.friend_one= U.id
END
AND F.status = 1
```

(http://www.9lessons.info/2014/03/facebook-style-friend-request-system.html)

[image: Table Structure]

However, selecting results from friends table with 7500 records takes 1.5 seconds. Is there a way to solve this problem? I am not an expert in sql. The explain shows that I am doing ALL select which I think causing the trouble.

[image: Explain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off with `union` or `union all` than in using `or` or `case` in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT F.friend_one, F.friend_two, F.requested_id, F.status
FROM users U JOIN
     friends F
     ON F.status = 1 AND F.friend_one = 2 AND F.friend_two = U.id
UNION ALL
SELECT F.friend_one, F.friend_two, F.requested_id, F.status
FROM users U JOIN
     friends F
     ON F.status = 1 AND F.friend_two = 2 AND F.friend_one= U.id;
```

You may also want to have indexes.  I would recommend `friends(status, friend_two, friend_one)` and `friends(status, friend_one, friend_two)`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. One more question. Does order of columns in index key matter? or it is just a sake or readability. p.s. SO says I cannot accept answers too fast! I will accept it when SO allows :) cheers!

Comment: @Inacio . . . The order of keys in the index matters, which is why this answer recommends two different indexes.